# Is there any free solution to remove unneeded architectures from Universal ppc/intel binaries?

Tags: universal-binaries

I am aware about an application that is able to remove unneeded architectures from Universal binaries - [XSlimmer](http://www.xslimmer.com/).

Still, I am looking for a free solution for this because I am not willing to pay for this kind of service.

Comment: You probably know already, but just be aware that removing 'unneeded' architectures can cause software update issues due to checksum failures and other such problems, so make sure you have a good backup first. For the amount of disk space you're likely to save, I'm never convinced it's worth the risk.

Comment: The amount of disk space you can save is huge, this is why I am interested in this solution.

Comment: On my system, where I have almost 200 applications in /Applications, Monolingual removed about 10 GB of data. On my wife's system, where there are far fewer applications, it removed 3 GB of data. I removed languages and architectures.

Comment: Well okay, I suppose it depends on your definition of 'huge', but I still consider the adage 'disk space is cheap' to be be worth bearing in mind here. If you're sweating over 10GB or less, it's probably time to think about upgrading your hard drive anyway-- OS X performance will be starting to degrade with so little free space, and it's probably taken you a year or two to fill it up that much, so you'll probably be somewhat nearer the end of the drive's mechanical life than its beginning.

Comment: I have a 500GB disk and yes it's not so big, if you use it with two versions of xcode, two os version, a windows with visual studio inside, and some music....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Monolingual](http://monolingual.sourceforge.net/) will remove extraneous languages and architectures and is open source.

Answer (score 6):

All tools to manipulate architectures in binaries are covers over [lipo](https://ss64.com/osx/lipo.html) the command line tool that Apple supplies as part of the Developer tools

Comment: Thanks, now I just have to hope that someone will write a script that would use lipo :)

Comment: lipo -remove ppc executable

Comment: Note, too, that `lipo -info filenamehere` will list the architectures an app includes, in case you're uncertain.

Comment: Based on this it shouldn't be too hard to create a script that does the cutting for `/Applications/`. Also it should have a blacklist, I'm sure there will be applications that will fail to work if you play with them.

Comment: Unfortunately, most of the apps in /Applications are SIP-protected.  Disabling and re-enabling SIP is a nuisance, and you'd have to repeat it frequently due to software update.