# Saving space by thinning universal intel/arm binaries

Tags: storage, universal-binaries

I have no ARM CPUs on any of my laptops or desktops.  If ever I get a computer new enough, it will already have all the binaries it needs or will get them from updates.  So there is no justification for them to consume 90 GB¹ on my internal drive.

I can reclaim that space by disabling SIP, using `ditto` to thin them while copying to somewhere else, copying them back where they belong, and re-enabling SIP.  Pretty clumsy to have to do after **every** software update.  Is there a better way?

¹assuming an ARM binary is about the same size as an Intel.

Comment: I don't see any way to revert the edit, but neither the question nor the answer is limited to any particular architecture.  It's possible for an intel/PPC binary to exist and run on a machine with SIP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just how other tools do it, like CleanMyMac does with Universal apps (not sure if it's been updated for Universal 2 yet). There doesn't appear to be a better solution than manually removing the other architecture from each app, which can be done with some tools (see [Is there any free solution to remove unneeded architectures from Universal binaries?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/14964/37797)) and these can be made to loop over a given folder of applications.

There are more steps required than just disabling SIP to do this with Big Sur's own applications now that Big Sur boots from a sealed APFS snapshot. [Can I mount the root (system) filesystem as writable in Big Sur?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/395508/37797) goes into the steps required to make a modification to the bootable snapshot, but the modification you make to remove the other architecture is the same.

Comment: Well, it looks like the answer is NO (there isn't a better way).  But I'll change the accept if someone does come up with one.