# Thin universal application recursively

Tags: macos, high-sierra, universal-binaries

I'm running on a 2017 macbook pro so I don't need arm64 architecture. I can thin the application manually by going to each executable and library and use `lipo` to extract the x86_64 architecture, but it's very time-consuming for applications with many frameworks/libraries embedded.

Is there a software or a way to thin universal application recursively? It need to:

- identify all files that are executables/libraries and contains both x86_64 and arm64 in the application bundle, and for each file:
- extract the x86_64 part of the file
- replace the original file with the thinned file
- preferably, restore the modified date of the folder containing the file

Note that the two solutions [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14964/is-there-any-free-solution-to-remove-unneeded-architectures-from-universal-ppc-i) does not answer my question because Monolingual does not thin frameworks and libraries inside the application bundle and Xslimmer is discontinued.

Comment: My best bet would be to open an issue on Monolingual to request that feature

Comment: A) This will break the app's signatures.  B) Are you sure it's worth it? The space saved from the _executables_ is usually small compared to all the data (your own and that provided by app resources).

Comment: @DarkDust It will not. I have tested it. Simply put, there are separate signatures for each architecture, and deleting one will not break the app's signature.

Comment: Huh, you're right. Just checked with `otool`, there's a `LC_CODE_SIGNATURE` entry per architecture. Never noticed this, and I sometimes needed to look executables with an editor; signatures are indeed present multiple times. Still leaves the question: are you sure it's worth the effort? I'd simply write a small shell script, finding all executables using `find … -type f -perm +a=x …`, which will also find lots of files with executable bits that are not libraries or programs. You can try to filter these further using `file`, but `lipo` should ignore them anyway (with a warning).

Comment: @DarkDust For applications with chromium or electron framework, doing this basically cuts down the size by 1/2. i.e. 600 mb application becomes 300mb application. Since doing this have zero negative effects, I don't think it's a bad thing to do for large applications.